# Angular 7, How Sort An Observable Array With Sort() Method

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable, ng-bootstrap

I had an array of an object, something like this

```
projects$: projectDetailVM[];
```

And this array worked with this sort method very well,

```
  onSort({ column, direction }: SortEvent) {

    this.headers.forEach(header => {
      if (header.sortable !== column) {
        header.direction = '';
      }
    });

    if (direction === '') {
      this.projects$ = this.projects$;
    } else {
      this.projects$ = [...this.projects$].sort((a, b) => {
        const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
        return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
      });
    }
  }
```

So I am talking about this part of the method,

```
  this.projects$ = [...this.projects$].sort((a, b) => {
            const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
            return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
          });
```

Based on some requirements I forced to change the array to observable array, now I have,

```
 projects$: Observable<projectDetailVM[]>;
```

So, this sort() method no more works with array of observable,

```
   this.projects$ = [...this.projects$].sort((a, b) => {
        const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
        return direction === 'asc' ? res : -res;
      });
```

something like this,

[image]

Is there any option to sort array of observable, something like cast, or using some converters.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe try `this.projects$.pipe(map(data => data.sort([..])))`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fussel it is the solution, actually I tried this codes on some wrong ways but you solved it.